# Why need to truncate StringContent response for JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api

I have written WebApi filter to detect concurrency issues. In action OnActionExecuted I set response content like below:
[image]

```
actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent( "'{ \"hasValidationErrors\": true, \"validationErrors\": " + System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode( validationErrors ) + ", \"concurrencyIssue\": true }'", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/string" );
```

When I receive it and write to console it looks like on below printscreen

Then, When I try to do:

```
JSON.parse(response.data)
```

I get error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
```

but when I do

```
JSON.parse( response.data.substring(1, response.data.length - 1) )
```

it works as expected, mean convert string to json data.

So my question is, why I have to truncate response.data?
I gues that, as can be seen in first line on printscreen, there are additional quotemarks. But how can I create my server response to not put them there? And why, when I log `response.data` ( thrid line on printscreen ), there are only apostrophe, but no quotemarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your JSON is not valid. Try to create a model  class for your response. Then Parse.

Example :

```
public class Response
{
   public bool hasValidationErrors;
   //public YourType validationErrors;
   public bool concurrencyIssue;         
 }
 var obj = new Response();
 obj.hasValidationErrors = true;
 obj.concurrencyIssue = true;         
 var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
 //Set Your Response
```

Hope this helpful.

Comment: thanks a lot - Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject do its job.